# permission denied on files created via adb in recovery

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, twrp, file-permissions

I stumbled upon a strange issue - after installing new ROM (CyanogenMod 12.1), I used adb push (still in TWRP) to copy some backed up directories to internal storage - so far so good. But then in fully booted system I found out, that I have read only permission for these dirs even when logged as root (I can still remove them from recovery though; also I don't have this problem, when I use adb when normal android is running).

I thought that it could be a selinux issue, but `ls -lZ` shows the same permissions/context for everything (and I also tried calling the `restorecon` on these dirs)

Any idea what causes this?
(note: I'm looking just for explanation, I can solve this easily by deleting it in recovery)

EDIT: in case it was relevant, my device is Kindle Fire HD (tate)

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason (even on my AOSP 6 Xperia S) actual "fully booted system" reported permissions are a lie.

I eventually ran `ls -l` from recovery, and discovered not only they were different, but also owner was another one (in this case root, instead of media_rw).

`chown 1023.1023` and `chmod 770` did the work and made the file "normal".